# How to set best zoom for marker in google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have to show only one location at a time in the Google map with a marker.

I tried to use auto zoom & auto center using the following code:

```
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
bounds.extend(latlng);

map.fitBounds(bounds);   // auto zoom
map.panToBounds(bounds); // auto center
```

Also tried with the following:

```
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
bounds.extend(latlng);

map.setCenter(bounds.getCenter(), map.getBoundsZoomLevel(bounds));
```

Both the above solutions are giving the maximum zoom, since I am showing only one location in the map. With this maximum zoom I was not able to see the surrounding locations in the map.

Is there any solution to set zoom which gives a better view of map.

Giving the best zoom size (like 8, 9, 10....) which fits for all the locations also considerable one.

Thanks,
Gopal.

Comment: What do you mean by "the best zoom size (like 8, 9, 10....) which fits for all the locations"?  If you want to fit the zoom to multiple markers, create a google.maps.LatLngBounds that contains them all and call google.maps.Map.fitBounds on it.  You can then center the map on the particular marker in question.

Comment: Code in your comment resembling the code snippet in my question itself.
I have to show only one location. map.fitBounds() taking to the maximum available zoom for the specified location. So that I was not able to view the area surrounding the specified location.
I want to show map that is showing the surrounding locations along with the specified location.

Comment: _the best zoom size (like 8, 9, 10....) which fits for all the locations_ means, if I use the zoom size as specified in the following snippet:
`var mapOptions = {
             center: latlng,
             zoom: 10,
             mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
       };`

I need a specific zoom size which is optimistic for most of the location types like - Street, State, Country, ...

Answer (score 0):

Please Refer link: http://jsfiddle.net/ZqhPM/3

```
       var mapOptions = {
             center: new google.maps.LatLng(39.8634242, -97.28818149999998),
             zoom: 8,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
       };
```

If you want to increase zoom level. please change zoom option in mapOptions.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I know the way to specify zoom property. Here I am asking for a zoom size which fits for the location types like - Street, City, State, ...

Comment: Please try to use google geocode administrative area_level_2 for finding the location type. Then based on location type set zoom size.

Answer (score 0):

> I need a specific zoom size which is optimistic for most of the location types like - Street, State, Country

If you know the street, state or city, the [geocoder](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding) will [return](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#GeocodingResults) a google.maps.LatLngBounds object for that geocoded result (and sometimes 2, a viewport and a bounds, see the documentation).

[State (Massachusetts)](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_example_geo2.asp?addr1=Massachussetts&geocode=1)

[Country (France)](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_example_geo2.asp?addr1=France&geocode=1)

[Street (Broadway, Arlington, MA)](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_example_geo2.asp?addr1=Broadway,%20Arlington,%20MA&geocode=1)